# How to add 'Categories' heading to categories block in sidebar?

Tags: theme-twenty-sixteen

I recently started blogging again after years and was experimenting with new themes. However, when I tried to switch back to the old Kubrick theme, I wasn't able to as it has been retired. After spending some time to find a replacement which had the same simplicity, I selected the Twenty Sixteen theme - https://twentysixteendemo.wordpress.com/?demo .

I added blocks for Archive and Categories to my website (https://nprateeks.wordpress.com/) but I am not able to figure how to add the title/heading to the 2 blocks. For example, I see the list of categories but not the word Categories at the top of the block like it does in the demo.

How do I add those titles?

Demo:[image: Demo:]

My website:
[image: My website:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When WordPress used [Widgets](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/manage-wordpress-widgets/) each widget had a Title field, and this is what you're seeing in the demo. On a new Install of WordPress, however, Widgets will be largely replaced with [Blocks](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/block-based-widgets-editor/), and Blocks do not have titles. In block-based themes you would be expected to add a separate Heading block. Older themes, such as Twenty Sixteen, support placing Blocks where you could previously place Widgets.

On these themes, if you want to use their Widget title styles, you can insert the [Widget Group](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/09/22/core-editor-improvement-introducing-the-widget-group-block/) block. This inserts a generic Widget that can have a title and a block as its content. If you add a Widget Group with an Archive or Categories block you should be able to replicate what you see in the demo.

Alternatively, and I wouldn't recommend this for new sites, you could install the [Classic Widgets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-widgets/) plugin, which will restore the classic widgets interface and the Widgets themselves, with their title fields. This won't do anything for newer block-based themes, but it will work well for older themes that were built to support Widgets.

Comment: Thank you Jacob. I was able to add titles using widget groups.